# Delete a context record from grid in kendo UI using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, kendo-ui

Hi Im using kendo ui grid in my project.

This is my code to insert records in database.

```
 public static void Insert(StudentViewModel student)
        {
            student.StudentId = All().OrderByDescending(p => p.StudentId).First().StudentId + 1;

            //All().Insert(0, student);
             UniRegEntities uniRegEntities = new UniRegEntities();
            Student stu =new Student();
            stu.FName = student.FirstName;
            stu.LName = student.LastName;
            stu.Gender = uniRegEntities.Genders.Where(x => x.Title == student.Gender).FirstOrDefault();
            stu.Id = student.StudentId;

            uniRegEntities.Students.Add(stu);
            uniRegEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
```

And this is my update statement.

```
 public static void Update(StudentViewModel student)
        {
          UniRegEntities context = new UniRegEntities();
            var studentToUpdate = context.Students.Where(x => x.Id == student.StudentId).FirstOrDefault();
            studentToUpdate.FName = student.FirstName;
            studentToUpdate.LName = student.LastName;
            studentToUpdate.Gender = context.Genders.Where(x => x.Title == student.Gender).FirstOrDefault();
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Anyone can suggest me the delete method?

Comment: DeleteObject before SaveChanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either get an entity from the DB and then delete it or create one and then delete it.

So:

```
var e = // Get
ctx.DeleteObject(e);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
var e = new Foo() { FooId = id };
ctx.Entity.Attach(e);
ctx.DeleteObject(e);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Applied to your situation:

You are getting a record so you want to use `DeleteObject()`

```
public static void Update(StudentViewModel student)
{
    UniRegEntities context = new UniRegEntities();

    var studentToDelete = context.Students.Where(x => x.Id == student.StudentId).FirstOrDefault();

    context.Students.DeleteObject(studentToUpdate);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: should I add reference for DeleteObject?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: DeleteObject() is in System.Data.Objects

Comment: I used this code and it worked well


            UniRegEntities context = new UniRegEntities();
            
            var studentToDelete = context.Students.Where(x => x.Id == student.StudentId).FirstOrDefault();

            context.Students.Remove(studentToDelete);
            context.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below code snippet?

```
using (var db= new AppContext(ConnectionStr))
{
        try
        {
            con.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            var o = new Student { StudentId = student.StudentId };
            db.Students.Attach(o);
            db.Students.Remove(o);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Students.Remove(context.students.Single(x=>x.Id==student.Id));
```